# How to generate multiple patterns from regular expressions

Tags: regex

I would like to know a method to list all possible patterns from a regular expression.
For example, the regular expression:

```
(a(g|ag)|(a|b)g)|g
```

yields

```
ag (twice), aag, bg and g, correct?
```

Is the best listing method to draw the regular expression using Thompson's construction and then to parse through the generated NFA?

Comment: Depending on your regex, this list is potentially infinite. Hence I think that there is no common way to do that. But you can still brute force to make an exhaustive list for your specific pattern.

Comment: As @ArnaudDenoyelle already commented: the set of strings in the language may be infinite so it can be troublesome. I'm just guessing here, but assuming your RE's are relatively small and does not make use of repetitions like `*` and `+` it may be possible to generate all the strings in a reasonable amount of time.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Thompson construction and then explore all possibile paths in order to have all the strings matching your regex.
However, since a regex such as: `a*` define an infinite language, you should have some **stop** condition. (e.g. lenght of the generated strings, etc...)